# What is the difference between JAIN SIP and MJSIP?

Tags: java, api, sip, jain-sip, mjsip

I've been investigating various API options for making use of the SIP (Session Initiation Protocol) in Java.

So far I've narrowed it down to JAIN SIP and MJSIP but I can't figure out the difference between the two.

Can someone please explain why and when to choose one over the other?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I have used MJSIP for a month and am going to give JAIN-SIP a try. Some of the factors of switching are:

1) Support, activity seem to be stalled. Nothing new on the website since 2006.

2) It is missing some higher level functionality like out-band DTMF tone generation

further, JAIN-SIP looks to be under active development http://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/job/jain-sip/

Comment: You can check JAIN SIP at http://code.google.com/p/jain-sip/, we just added SIP Over WebSockets and NIO to interact with WebRTC types of client. Professional Support is available from TeleStax, see http://telestax.com/2012/05/22/telestax-now-offers-commercial-grade-support-for-jain-sip/

Comment: I've used both for awhile now and just converted a build of red5phone to jain-sip. I prefer standards (jain-sip) over non-standard or unmaintained projects; its that simple for me.

Answer (score 4):

MJSIP's licence is a GNU style license, which you may or may not have to be careful about.

Comment: what is the license of JAIN-SIP?